# Issue with making acceptable input

Tags: java

im running into an issue where i have a code that's supposed to let you enter multiple integers and then searching for a specific integer in those integers. 
The issue i have is where the input is an integer and then a word. (example: 4 Java) 
Other then that the code is working as intended but at the specific answer of an int then an word it still reads as correct input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Random rng = new Random();
boolean Finished = true;
boolean Försök = true;
int Mitt = rng.nextInt(100)+1; 
int Head;

while (Finished == true){ 
 System.out.println(Mitt);
     String S = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Var god gissa vilket heltal jag                        valt! \n Du kan skriva in max 5 heltal varje gissning!");
 // allows you to enter 5 integers
   if (S == null|| (S != null && ("".equals(S)))){
System.exit(0);
}

   Scanner Svar = new Scanner(S);
if (Svar.hasNextInt() == false || Pattern.matches("[a-öA-Ö ]+", S)) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, var god skriv in ett heltal");
   Mitt = rng.nextInt(100)+1; 

}
else {


ArrayList<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

while (Svar.hasNextInt() && Finished == true){

   Head = Svar.nextInt();

    mylist.add(Head);   
      if (mylist.size()>5){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tyvärr skrev du in mer än 5 heltal!   \n Var god mata in igen!");
    Försök = false;
    break;
    } 

    System.out.println(mylist);

    if ( Head>100 || Head<0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tyvärr skrev du in ett heltal som var över 100 eller mindre än 0! \n Var god mata in igen!");
    Försök = false;
    break;
    }


 if (mylist.contains(Mitt)){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ayo du svarade rätt med " + Mitt);
  System.exit(0);

 }

  else if (Försök == true){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tyvärr svarade du fel! du kan försöka igen! rätt svar är " + Mitt);

  }

  }
  }



  }





  }
    }
```

Comment: So, what should it do when you enter "4 Java" ? Raising an error and exiting would seem reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you think you check for this validity?
You only check whether the first token is a number and after that you simply read until no more numbers are found. So as long as your first token is a number it is seen as valid input by your code.

Next time please use a debugger. Such questions are off-topic here.